# SQLiteNetExtensions multiple ManyToOne relations of same type

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net-extensions

I'm trying xamarin app... and I needed sqlite database... that contain 3 tables... users, accounts and transactions... the table of account seems:

```
[Table(nameof(Account))]
class Account
{
    [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(User))]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public double Balance { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

I think there is no problem until here...
but in transaction table there are tow columns, `FirstAccountId` and `TargetAccountId`,so I  like that:

```
[Table(nameof(Transaction))]
class Transaction
{
    [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Account))]
    public int TargetAccountId { set; get; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Account))]
    public int FirstAccountId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfTransaction { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne()]
    public Account Account1 { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne()]
    public Account Account2 { get; set; }`
}
```

How I can make `Account1` is the account for `FirstAccountId` and `Account2` is the account for `TargetAccountId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source code of `ManyToOne` ([see here](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/8febda909abc74b62330b92e5480830925116ed7/SQLiteNetExtensions/Attributes/ManyToOneAttribute.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)), it takes an `string foreignKey` as a parameter. I did not find anything about it in the documentation, but I'd assume that you can specify an foreign key explicitly using this parameter, although I did not find anything about it in the documentation

```
[ManyToOne(nameof(FirstAccountId))]
public Account Account1 { get; set; }

[ManyToOne(nameof(TargetAccountId))]
public Account Account2 { get; set; }
```

Comment: yes it worked, thank you, I would you to help me in another problem please .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982308/custom-viewcell-contain-button-has-command-and-binding-to-this-command ... it is the problem's link