# Custom ViewCell Contain Button Has Command And Binding To This Command

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I fix customize some problems in some projects
one of them that I need to use custom `ViewCell` in Separated class and file
like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          x:Class="HBRS.Controls.ViewCellTemplates.ArticleItemViewCell">
    <Image>
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer   
                    Command="{Binding BindingContext.clickCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=mArt}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</ViewCell>
```

where `mArt` is the view that will command make some thing with it

after that I used this view cell in on of my `xamarin` pages like that:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Cell:ArticleItemViewCell />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

when I run the application on my device, it throw an exception say that **cannot find object referenced for 'mArt'**
so I need some way to pass `Source={x:Reference Name=mArt}` up with the same result or make the interact that command will make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you wrote, I assume that you have a view using your `ViewCell` something like

```
<ContentView ...
    x:Name="mArt">
    <ListView ...>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <templates:ArticleItemViewCell ... />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentView>
```

And now you are trying to reference that view `mArt` from your `ViewCell`. Unfortunately that is not how things work. `mArt` is not something like a global variable, but a member of your view class (if you are interested in the details, have a look at the `.xaml.g.cs` file that is created in your object folder).

`ArticleItemViewCell` however is a *different class* from which you can't simply access fields of some other class. `ArticleItemViewCell` does not know anything about `mArt`. While it *might* be possible to access the parent in some way, I'd advise you no to, because you tend to forget these details and some months later you'll look at your view and wonder where the interaction with the cell is implemented, until you realize, that the cell does some fishy things. It will only cost you time. Been there, done that. Believe me.

Rather create a bindable property of type `Command` in your viewcell, and bind to it from your containing view

In ArticleItemViewCell.xaml.cs

```
public static readonly BindableProperty TappedCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TappedCommand), typeof(Command), typeof(ArticleItemViewCell)); 

public Command TappedCommand
{
    get => (Command)GetValue(TappedCommandProperty);
    set => SetValue(TappedCommandProperty, value);
}
```

And now you can bind them from your `ArticleItemViewCell`

```
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          x:Class="HBRS.Controls.ViewCellTemplates.ArticleItemViewCell"
          x:Name="Cell">
    <Image>
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer   
                    Command="{Binding TappedCommand, Source={x:Reference Cell}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</ViewCell>
```

And from your view you can bind the `clickCommand` of your VM

```
<ContentView ...
    x:Name="mArt">
    <ListView ...>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <templates:ArticleItemViewCell TappedCommand="{Binding Source={x:Reference mArt}, Path=BindingContext.clickCommand}" ... />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentView>
```

I did not try the exact code, but basically this oughta work.

**Please note:** Consuming the `ItemTapped` event ([see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.itemtapped?view=xamarin-forms)) with a event to command behavior ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior)) is more expressive and spares you the additional command.

Comment: thank you soooo much, I appreciate your efforts, it's work so good.

Comment: I'm trying to follow this to solve my issue but no luck. Any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62718381/button-in-custom-viewcell-xamarin-tableview-c-sharp